# Spring injection with Vaadin Views

Tags: java, spring, annotations, vaadin

I'm trying to create a Vaadin and Spring based web app which consists of few different views. The problem I have is basically the communication between these different views, or classes, if you will.

In the initial view the user is to create "player" objects that are then used later during the session, in different views. Currently I have four classes (of which here the Player -class is omitted):

```
@Route("")
public class InitOptionsView extends VerticalLayout {
       public InitOptionsView(@Autowired PlayerController playerController) {

              // other stuff...

              for(Player p : players) { 
                playerController.addHomePlayer(p);
            }

              UI.getCurrent().navigate("shot");
        }
}

@Component
@VaadinSessionScope
public class PlayerController {
    private final ArrayList<Player> playersHome = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addHomePlayer(Player p) {
        playersHome.add(p);
    }

    public ArrayList<Player> getHomePlayers() {
        return playersHome;
    }
}

@Route(value = "shot", layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle("Laukaus")
@CssImport("./styles/views/laukaus/laukaus-view.css")
public class ShotView extends VerticalLayout {

    public ShotView(@Autowired PlayerController playerController) {
        for(Player p : playerController.getHomePlayers()) {
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The list "playerController.getHomePlayers()" is null.

I tried to use the vaadin documentation behind this link:
https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/spring/tutorial-spring-scopes.html

I'm very new to Spring, annotations etc. and to my believing the solution lies in annotations and injections, but after an exhaustive googling I'm still at the starting point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The list cannot be null because you initialize it. Do you mean the list is emtpy?

Comment: From a quick glance the code looks good to me. You say that `playerController.getHomePlayers()` is null, do you mean that it's empty? Because it's final so you shouldn't be able to set it to null. If you're comfortable with debugging, check that after adding the players in the init view, they are indeed in the list. Also check that both views get a reference to the same `PlayerController`, it should show something like `{PlayerController@123}` or `PlayerController (id=123)` depending on your IDE, and the number should be the same.